# How to hide the backgrond when opacity is applied in SVG?

Tags: css, svg

I have applied color in an SVG image with half opacity. The background image is visible, but how do you hide that image? I have given the original image color applied the image for your reference.
[image]

How do I hide the background lines?

I have given a color applied SVG tag:

```
<g id="svg_1" fill-opacity="0.5" style="pointer-events:inherit">
```

The above tag has fill opacity and color applied in each path have the same color.

Comment: so u dont want the background black lines to be invisible on green part?

Comment: Yes i dont want background visible part

Comment: itha eppadi apply panrathu. konjam dout ta irukku

Comment: vera vazhi illaya bro

Comment: This solution not convenient for me. Thanks for your care

Comment: okay sure i will do

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this using opacity. opacity will show the background of the layer behind.

Instead, u place an image or create a shape of light green bg-color u need like opacity.